# Get "[SceneKit] Error:" when set AVPlayer to SCNMaterial.diffuse.contents

Tags: scenekit, arkit

According Apple's docs, `SCNMaterial.diffuse.contents` can be a `AVPlayer`.
In this case material appear content of video.

Everything seems ok but I get several sceneKit error logs:

```
 [SceneKit] Error: Could not get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)
```

Below is my code. Move `[_player play]` to `viewWillAppear` does't help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.boxNode = [self.sceneView.scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"box" recursively:YES];
    NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/VRF_SuLie.MP4"];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    _player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
    self.boxNode.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = _player;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [_player play];
}
```

How to avoid this error?

Comment: On which iPhone model was this tested?

Comment: Test on iOS12.0 .

Comment: that's the software version. Was it an iPhone X, iPhone 6, etc. ?

Comment: Sorry, It is iPhone X.

Comment: Does the video play?

Comment: @JoshRobbins Yes. It looks fine but with some error logs.

Comment: Im having same issue, did you fix it?

Comment: @Mr.KLD No, I just ignore it Because it only happen on iOS 12.

Comment: Also seeing this on macOS mojave

Comment: Still seeing this on iOS 16.1, iPadOS 16.1 and macOS Ventura 13.1. The log messages wouldn't be so bad if the node didn't flash white for each rendered frame that SceneKit thinks is missing. I spent some time debugging this and it looks like it may be some kind of clock skew between SceneKit's system clock and the AVPlayerItem clock. I've yet to figure out how to solve it though. Interestingly SpriteVideoNode does not exhibit this problem.